# Streaming JSON to browser with GZIP

Tags: json, http, gwt, jetty, gzip

I'm trying to convert some JSON streaming to pass through a GZIPFilter which I wrote. So far I have been able to tune the filter to flush when I tell it to and it probably outputs compatible gzip browser data.
I redirected the output to a file and run gzip -cd -v test.gz which produced the expected output and then 'unexpected end of file'.

The problem is the browser still sees zero output (firebug) so I was wondering whether partial flushes to a gzip stream are interpreted by the browser.

The stream contains mostly javascript instructions/objects and should be received and parsed on the client side. The servlet is called once and kept open for the entire duration of the session, supplying the client with data; the connection is not closed so the stream keeps running providing a kind of push data from the server.

My setup:
WinXP 32bit,
GWT 2.4.0,
Jetty7.4..,
GzipFilter (with tweaks),
Firefox 8 / Chrome 10

As far as I know per RFC specs the content is decoded only after the stream ends, so what I am trying to do might not be possible. However you might have some suggestions to make this work on major browsers.

Later Edit:

- GzipFilter is specified through web.xml and it is ok
- the browser receives Content-Encoding: gzip
- bytes are being written to the HTTPResponse stream
- tested in both compiled and live GWT mode
- tested with charsets iso-8859-1 or none specified
- content-type is text/html
- without the filter applied through web.xml everything works

Comment: What's the reason for writing your own gzip filter instead of using jetty's one?

Comment: Fixed it. I will write the details after I'm allowed to submit my answer. I'm doing this because flushes on the GzipFilter do not register until the outputStream is closed so if you are trying to do real-time streaming this won't work.

Comment: it'd be nice to include your motivation in the question, there might be others having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I was using a custom intermediary OutputStream for debugging purposes which wrote the output to a file and also some statistics and I think I left some methods un-overriden. Once I removed this it is working.

My parameters, for the ones curious enough:

- buffer size: 8k
- min gzip size: 64b
- to flush the gzip stream you need to extend GzipStream, override the flush method to set the compression level to zero and then back again, deflate()-ing in between.
- replace the gzOut stream assignment operation with the one pointing to this custom Gzip/Deflater Stream

As I stated already, the reason for doing this is live streaming of JSON objects to the browser, without closing the socket. This is until all browsers implement WebSocket properly. For doing push data you either need a WebSocket implementation or you need an always open connection that the server can push data through.

Later edit: after reinventing the wheel: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4255743